# Laravel auth not working after several seconds

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, bcrypt

I have build an application using laravel. Yesterday I have put the application live, but I have a lot of problems with the authentication. No one can login except when they reset their password, and then it works once.

I have tested this using the following controller.

```
<?php

class AdminController extends \BaseController {

    public function getResetPw($id, $pw) {
            //Log updaten en naar de database sturen
            $log = new UserLog;
            $log->status = 'Changepw:' . $id;
            $log->save();

            // Start password changing.
            $user = User::find($id);

            if ($user == null)
                return "No valid user";

            $user->password = Hash::make($pw);
            $user->save();

            return "Password set for " . $user->username . ". ('" . $pw . "', '" . $user->password . "')<br /><br />Check: " . Auth::attempt(array('username' => $user->username, 'password' => $pw));
        }

        public function getTestPw($id, $pw) {
            // Start password changing.
            $user = User::find($id);

            if ($user == null)
                return "No valid user";

            return Auth::attempt(array('username' => $user->username, 'password' => $pw)) . "";
        }
}
```

First I cal the `getResetPw` function to set my new password, then I call `getTestPw` to test this. I refresh the page every second and it returns `1` about 5 times and then the auth becomes invalid. Meaning I can no longer login.

These are the routes for the above functions:

```
Route::get('/admin/pwreset/{id}/{pw}', 'AdminController@getResetPw')->where('id', '\d+');
Route::get('/admin/pwtest/{id}/{pw}', 'AdminController@getTestPw')->where('id', '\d+');
```

Could this be because of invalid characters in my encryption key? This is my encryption key (with some letters replaced): `ROOzr*Dqmoense_se_emvnqmd!*tft7e`

Thank you for helping.

**Update:**
This is te code for logging in:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $message = "";  // Het errorbericht dat moet worden weergegeven.

    //We prepareren een log voor in de database
    $log = new UserLog;

    // Zijn alle gegevens ingevuld?
    if (Input::has('txtUsername') && Input::has('txtPassword'))
    {
        $log->username = Input::get('txtUsername');

        // Controlleer de ingevulde gegevens.
                    //$auth = User::where("username", "=", Input::get('txtUsername'))->first();
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('txtUsername'), 'password' => Input::get('txtPassword'))))
        //if (Hash::check(Input::get("txtPassword"), $auth->password))
                    {
                        //Auth::login($auth);

                        //Log updaten en naar de database sturen
                        $log->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                        $log->status = 'LoginSuccess';
                        $log->save();

                        return Redirect::intended('/user');
        }
        else
        {
                        $log->status = 'LoginFailed';
                        $log->save();

                        $message = "Geen geldige gegevens.";

                        // If the username is known, let the webmasters know.
                        if (User::where('username', '=', Input::get('txtUsername'))->count() > 0)
                        {
                            $data = array(
                                "username" => Input::get('txtUsername'),
                                "ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                                "user_agent" => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
                            );
                            Role::find(1)->sendMail(
                                'KLJ Loginpoging (' . Input::get('txtUsername') . ')', 
                                'emails.auth.loginAttempt', 
                                $data
                            );
                        }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Vul alle velden in aub.";
    }

    return View::make('login.login')->with('message', $message);
}
```

Comment: Its more likely a problem with your session. What session driver are you using?

Comment: I am using the default `file` driver. I haven't changed anything in  session.php

Comment: I have tried all other drivers as well, but I get the same result.

Comment: Your encryption key is fine. Could you add your routes to your question? Are you sure you're not calling getResetPw() from anywhere else?

Comment: I have added the routes. But the problem happens on any login form or password reset.